# Php необъявленные переменные по умолчанию

Tags: php

Собственно php у нас не требует жестких объявлений переменных как C++. Поэтому я ставлю настройки ошибок жесткие, что бы не забывать объявлять переменные, однако есть ли такой параметр в php.ini, что бы всем необъявленным переменным выставлял значение к примеру false ?

Comment: NULL не устроит ?

Comment: вообще если об этом думать то сделайте так(для dev mode): http://ideone.com/vGULRF

Answer (score 1):

`error_reporting (E_ALL)` - самый что ни есть оптимальный и удобный вариант

Answer (score 0):

falsе это вполне себе определенное boolean значение . А null это спец тип.

Проще всего проверять и присваивать false оператором ?: